# Code to Uninstall imutils

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone please tell me the code to uninstall imutils from raspberry pi using python. 
using sudo apt-get --upgrade imutils
Error: cant find the location of imutils

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the `os` or `subprocess` module. With the `os` module:

```
import os
os.system("sudo apt-get remove imutils")
```

Now with the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sudo apt-get remove imutils", shell=True)
```